# How Linux finds out about illegal memory access error?

Tags: linux, system-calls, segmentation-fault

I have a question about how Linux traps memory access errors. As far as I know, a user space program doesn't need to ask operating system every time it wants to access memory, now when the process tries to access a memory location not in it's address space the CPU must be having a way to stop this and communicate this event to the OS.

So my question is:
How does the CPU inform the OS about this event ?
     Does it start executing a predefined code ? If yes, please let me know about where in memory is that code, what is that code section called, what does it do, etc.

Comment: Some relevant light reading here:  https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guesses seem about 100% correct.

There is hardware called a **memory management unit (MMU)** (Part of CPU). It is given page tables, that describe what pages do what (what are executable, readable, writable). If a process tries to do what it is not allowed to do, then the MMU interrupts the CPU. The CPU then executes the code in the starting at a particular address. This address is defined in the **interrupt vector table**. A table of start addresses, for each interrupt type (some CPUs store instructions in this table, not addresses, but they do the same thing).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. It solved many of my other queries. Thanks again!!